# Древовидные комментарии на чистом PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Есть задание - написать древовидные комментарии на чистом PHP. Застрял на полпути и не знаю как продолжить писать код чтобы наконец-то уже что-то получилось. Написал функции записи комментариев в базу (addComment), их вывода (getComments) и их валидацию (dataValidation), на регулярку не обращайте внимания, будет допилена.
Каким образом мне дальше строить алгоритмы для реплаев? Модифицировать функцию addComment или писать новую addReply? Как делать запись родительского id в базу? хелп плиз!!

comments.php (Model)

```
function getComments()
{

    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=comments;charset=utf8", "root", "");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments";
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute();
    $comments = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $comments;
}

/**
 * Adding records from the form to database
 */
function addComment(string $name, string $content): void
{

    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=comments;charset=utf8", "root", "");

    $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (name, content) VALUES (:name, :content)";
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindParam("name", $name);
    $statement->bindParam("content", $content);
    $statement->execute();
}

/**
 * Validation of records put into the form
 */
function dataValidation()
{
    $errorMessage = [];

    $name = trim($_POST['name']);
    $content = trim($_POST['content']);
    $allowedSymbols = "/^[a-zA-Z-' ]*$/";
    $nameLength = 30;
    $contentLength = 1000;

    if (mb_strlen($name) > $nameLength) {
        $errorMessage['name'] = "Name should have less than 30 symbols";
    } if (mb_strlen($content) > $contentLength) {
        $errorMessage['content'] = "Commentary should have less than 1000 symbols";
    } if (empty($name)) {
        $errorMessage['name'] = "Enter your name";
    } if (empty($content)) {
        $errorMessage['content'] = "Enter your commentary";
    } if (!preg_match($allowedSymbols, $name)) {
        $errorMessage['name'] = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    } if (!preg_match($allowedSymbols, $content)) {
        $errorMessage['content'] = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }

    return $errorMessage;
}
```

controller.php

```
<?php

include "../comments.php";

$comments = getComments();

$errorMessage = [];

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    $errorMessage = dataValidation();

    if (empty($errorMessage)) {
        addComment($_POST['name'], $_POST['content']);
    }
}


include_once "../index.php";
```

index.php (View)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tree Comments</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="navbar">
        <a class="logo" href="#">Tree Comments Exercise</a>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <h2>Random Post</h2>
        <div class="post-row">
            Is allowance instantly strangers applauded discourse so. Separate entrance welcomed sensible laughing why
            one moderate shy. We seeing piqued garden he.
            As in merry at forth least ye stood. And cold sons yet with. Delivered middleton therefore me at. Attachment
            companions man way excellence how her pianoforte.
            Conveying or northward offending admitting perfectly my. Colonel gravity get thought fat smiling add but.
            Wonder twenty hunted and put income set desire expect.
            Am cottage calling my is mistake cousins talking up. Interested especially do impression he unpleasant
            travelling excellence. All few our knew time done draw ask.
            Greatest properly off ham exercise all. Unsatiable invitation its possession nor off. All difficulty
            estimating unreserved increasing the solicitude.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="commentaries">
        <?php include_once "errors.php" ?>
        <div class="comments-form">
            <h3>Leave a commentary</h3>
            <form action="controller.php" method="post">
                <div class="input">
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name" size="53">
                </div>
                <div class="textarea">
                    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="content" placeholder="Enter Comment"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="submit">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit_comment" id="submit_comment">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php foreach ($comments as $comment): ?>
            <div class="comments">
                <div class="comment-added-by">
                    By <b><?= htmlspecialchars($comment['name'], ENT_QUOTES); ?></b> on <?= $comment['date']; ?>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="comment-content">
                    <p><?= htmlspecialchars($comment['content'], ENT_QUOTES); ?></p>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="comments-reply-button">
                    <button onclick="document.getElementById('formreply-1').style.display='';">Reply</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="reply-form">
                <div style="display: none" action="#" id="formreply-<?= $comment['id']; ?>">
                    <div class="reply-name">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Your name" size="53">
                    </div>
                    <div class="reply-comment">
                        <textarea rows="2" cols="50" name="reply-content" placeholder="Enter Comment"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="reply-submit">
                        <button type="submit" id="submit-comment">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?= $comment['id']; ?>">
                </div>
                </form>
                <div class="comments">
                    <div class="comment-added-by">
                        By <b>Name</b> on 29-12-2021 00:05
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="comment-content">
                        <p>some reply</p>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="comments-reply-button2">
                        <button onclick="document.getElementById('formreply-1').style.display='';">Reply</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <script>

        </script>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

В базе данных: id (auto increment), parent_id (default = 0), name, content, date

Comment: А чем ответ отличается от комментария. Да только тем, что родительский id заполнен. Конечно это должна быть та же самая функция. Вы от браузера должны получать всегда этот parent_id, только он должен быть пустым когда комментарий корневой и не является ответом. (ну можно конечно его в таком случае не передавать, но с точки зрения php разницы быть не должно, не задан/пустой - корневой, задан - ответ).

Comment: И parent_id лучше сделать все таки NULL для корневых комментов и сделать foreign key с parent_id на id, что бы исключить вероятность ошибочного удаления родителя, при существующих дочерних элементах. В принципе, если посчитаете это правильным, можете на такой foreign повесить правило on delete cascade, что бы при удалении родительского коммента все дочерние удалялись на уровне БД.

Comment: а как именно дать понять браузеру что это ответ а не комментарий? то есть как именно мне в функции addComment это прописать? очень долго не могу самостоятельно разобраться с этим, поэтому и хочу попросить Вас помочь поконкретнее) спасибо

Comment: Так у вас на уровне html почти все уже есть. только вы почему то в форме ответа полям с именем пользователя и id коммента не задали атрибуты name и в итоге не получаете их значения когда вам форму отправляют. А так если зададите им имена, то просто посмотрите при получении данных от пользователя есть ли это самое поле с id комментария и явно передадите его третьим параметром в addComment

Answer (score 0):

Добавляете в таблицу comments поле parent_id и при добавлении комментариев задаете ему значение либо 0, что означает, что комментарий главный, либо id родительского комментария, к которому относится ответ.

Comment: БД должна контролировать целостность, во избежание появления комментариев относящихся к удаленным родителям. А для этого необходимо, что бы у корневого элемента parent_id был NULL, а не 0.

Answer (score 0):

Когда-то давно делал похожую вещь. Обычно все советуют делать что-то вроде такого

```sql
CREATE TABLE comments (id int not null auto_increment, parent_id not null, is_deleted smallint default 0, creator_id int not null, body varchar(255) not null)
```

С последующей рекурсивной выборкой по `parent_id` комментария. Однако при такой реализации есть проблемы - во-первых не все БД поддерживают рекурсивные запросы (mySQL по-моему только с 8-ой версии), во-вторых на многих хостингах время выполнения рекурсивных запросов и объем выделяемой под них памяти ограничивают. Я для себя решил эти проблемы изменением таблицы - `parent_id` сделал `text` и запихивал туда через `,` список `id` родителей - таким образом мне это позволяло в один запрос

```sql
SELECT * FORM comments WHERE id IN( ... )
```

получить список всех родителей указанного комментария и легко построить древовидную иерархию комментариев.

Добавление же `reply` тоже не занимало много времени - достаточно было скопировать от `родителя` его `parent_id` с добавлением в конец его же `id` и сохранить его в поле `ребенка`.

Таким образом Ваш класс работы с комментариями выглядел бы примерно так

```php
/**
 * Создание комментария
 * @param int $creator_id ИД пользователя-автора комментария
 * @param string $comment Текст комментария
 * @return boolean
 */
function createComment($creator_id = null, $comment = null )
{
    $result = false;
    if ( is_numeric($creator_id ) && intval($creator_id ) > 0 && !is_null($comment) && trim($comment) != '') {
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=comments;charset=utf8", "root", "");

        $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (creator_id, parent_id, body) VALUES (:creator_id, null, :body)";
        $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        if ( $statement !== false ) {
            $statement->bindParam("creator_id", $creator_id);
            $statement->bindParam("body", $comment);
            $result = $statement->execute();
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

/**
 * Ответ на комментарий другого пользователя
 * @param int $reply_id ИД комментария на который дается ответ
 * @param int $creator_id ИД пользователя-автора комментария
 * @param string $comment Текст комментария
 * @return boolean
 */
function replyToComment($reply_id = null, $creator_id = null, $comment = null )
{
    $result = false;
    if ( is_numeric($reply_id ) && intval($reply_id ) > 0 && is_numeric($creator_id ) && intval($creator_id ) > 0 && intval($reply_id ) != intval($creator_id ) && !is_null($comment) && trim($comment) != '') {
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=comments;charset=utf8", "root", "");
        $sql = "SELECT parent_id FROM comment WHERE id = :id";
        $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        if ( $statement !== false ) {
            $statement->bindParam("id", $reply_id);
            if ( $statement->execute() ) {
                $reply = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $reply .= ( $reply != '' ? ',' : '' ).$reply_id;
                $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (creator_id, parent_id, body) VALUES (:creator_id, :parent_id, :body)";
                $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                if ( $statement !== false ) {
                    $statement->bindParam("creator_id", $creator_id);
                    $statement->bindParam("parent_id", $reply);
                    $statement->bindParam("body", $comment);
                    $result = $statement->execute();
                }

            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

/**
 * Получение всех родителей указанного комментария
 * @param int $id ИД комментария
 * @param array $parentsList Возвращаемый массив со список всех родителей
 * @return boolean
 */
function getCommentParents($id = null, &$parentsList = null )
{
    $result = false;
    if ( is_numeric($id ) && intval($id ) > 0 ) {
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=comments;charset=utf8", "root", "");
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM comment WHERE id IN ( SELECT parent_id FROM comment WHERE id = :id )";
        $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        if ( $statement !== false ) {
            $statement->bindParam("id", $reply_id);
            if ( $statement->execute() ) {
                $parentsList = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $result = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

P.S В коде могут быть ошибки т.к давно не писал под `mySQL+PDO`

Comment: Родителей то действительно легко получить, когда у вас уже есть конкретный дочерний коммент в php, просто подставив список в IN. Но не понятно, в какой ситуации может это потребоваться. Всегда хочется получить наоборот детей конкретного родителя, чем список родителей облегчает это ? Если уж искать родителей то интересно  другая ситуация, у вас есть список id нескольких комментариев как получить за один запрос их родителей, такой IN как предложено на стороне БД не сформируешь

Comment: Предположим, нам надо позволить удалить какой нибудь комментарий с перевешиванием всех его детей к его родителю. Как это выполнить когда храниться список родителей. ведь менять придется рекурсивно все уровни ниже, а не только непосредственных детей

Comment: @Mike 1) детей родителя говорите? `WHERE parent_id LIKE '%,pid,%'` чем Вам не подходит?

Comment: @Mike  2) ситуация с удалением комментария и "перевешиванием" его детей бессмысленна т.к "дети" как правило являются ответом на "родителя" и "перевесив" детей-детей Вы рискуете получить "портянку" не подходящих по смыслу ответов (например: "Какого цвета у Вас обычно ручка?" на него дан ответ "Синяя", на "Синяя" кто-то дал ответ "Да не синяя, а красная" - удалив "Синяя" и "перевесив" - "Да не синяя.." сразу к "Какого цвета.." получите бессмыслицу. Впрочем `UPDATE comment set parent_id=replace(',:pid,', '') WHERE parent_id LIKE '%,:pid,%'` решит и эту надуманную ситуацию.

Comment: @phpBear `WHERE parent_id LIKE '%,pid,%'` А если нужный pid в начале или конце строки?

Comment: @phpBear `WHERE parent_id LIKE '%,pid,%'` такое условие не может использовать для поиска индекс, даже если он есть, и приведет к гарантированному полному сканированию всей таблицы, что даже на жалких сотне тысяч записей приведет к тормозам

Comment: @Mike `А если нужный pid в начале или конце строки?` - всегда обрамляйте `id` в `,` - это решит Вашу проблему даже если `id` состоит из одной записи

Comment: @phpBear Если в начале - то индекс поможет, если в конце то нет. Это как с алфавитным справочником, по началам слов искать легко, открыв нужную букву и быстро листая. А вот если первой буквы нет, то только вычитывая все

Comment: @Mike `такое условие не может использовать для поиска...` - зависит от СУБД. Тот же `mySQL` после того как его купил `oracle` довольно сильно продвинулся как по функционалу так и по оптимизации алогритмов, в том числе и полнотекстового поиска. Если же взять `postgreSQL` - там таких проблем вообще нет, либо можно вообще уйти в сторону `json` (но с ним свои заморочки). Если же с полнотекстовым поиском в выбранной СУБД совсем дело швах - реализуйте связку `один ко многим`.

Comment: @phpBear Полнотекстовый поиск mysql ничего не даст для поиска по указанному условию. Это специализированный вид поиска предназначенный для работы с естественным языком. он не индексирует произвольные места строки, он выделяет слова (причем игнорируя совсем короткие) выделяет их корни и вот с ними работает. В Postgresql да можно использовать триграм индекс. Но там лучше делать не строку, а int массив и gin индекс на него. Но там это не требуется так как рекурсивные запросы отлично справляются. Кстати, в mysql любой версии рекурсивно искать можно, но это громоздко и медленно

Comment: @Mike к сожалению мои познания в различиях полнотекстового поиска в зависимости от СУБД явно не столько глубоки как Ваши - так, что тут я спорить не буду. Как говориться, снимаю пред Вами шляпу. Как бы там ни было - я предложил свое решение автору задачи, которое явно не идеально, но все же надеюсь ему поможет хоть как-то. Решать ему. Ну, а нам с Вами похоже нужно прекращать дискуссию - иначе наша беседа грозит затянуться не на одну страницу :)